# Writing the contents to a file from input stream

Tags: java, io, streaming

I want to write the inputstream into a file in java. How to write the contents into a text file in java?

```
         try {

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

            //I want to write the content to a file line by line here
                 while (!in.ready()) {}

                 System.out.print("'\n");
                 in.close();
            }
```

Comment: google it and you will get your ans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
       FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("fileName");
        BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

            fbw.write(line + "\n");

        }
```