# Converting webpage into HTML

Tags: java, html

I want to convert a webpage into an HTML  page programatically.
I searched many sites but only providing details like converting into pdf format etc.
For my program now I'm saving a page as .html and then extracting the necessary data.
Is there any way to convert the webpage to an html page? Can anyone help me?
Any help would be appreciated.

Well I can explain in detail

I am extracting the names of users who like a page which i'm admin of . So I found a link https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=pageid where i can find the list of users. So for getting it first of all i have to save it as a .html page and then extract necessary data. So here I'm converting it into .html and then extract the data. But what I need is that convert that page into an HTML page using my program. I hope my question is clear now

Comment: What do you mean by converting a webpage into an HTML page? Aren't they same?

Comment: What do you want to convert to HTML page? Do you mean you want to generate HTML page with Java?

Comment: what do you want from this conversion?

Comment: Perhaps you question is how to programmatically fetch a web page?

Comment: Do you mean converting a web page to a *standalone* HTML page that can be used offline? Should it be a single HTML file or can it be a collection of files (possibly packaged as a zip file)? Please clarify by editing the question (including its title).

Comment: @nicael I have editted my question

Comment: @OskarsPakers I know it. But in this case this is a facebook page

Comment: @TechAgent your assumption is somewhat right. Now I have edited my question.Plz take a look. I hope it will be clear for u know and I need your suggestions for this

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides the following code snippet for programmatically retrieving an html page [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html).

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Instead of printing to console, you can save the contents to a file by using a FileWriter and BufferedWriter (example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663346/writing-the-contents-to-a-file-from-input-stream)):

```
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("fileName");
    BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

        fbw.write(line + "\n");

    }
```

Comment: thank u for your reply. But it's not what I want.I have edited my question and explained it more clearly. Plz take a look. I'm sure that you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Webpages are already HTML, if you want to save a webpage as HTML you can do this via the ***Firefox > Save Page As*** menu on Firefox. Or through ***File*** menu on other browsers.

If you need to download multiple pages in HTML from the same website or from a list of URLs there is a software that will make it easier for you: http://www.httrack.com/

Comment: the user is asking how to do it programatically